# OutlinedTextField's Text Color Does Not Change When Disabled

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I modified my textfield according to this article. [TextFieldDefaults](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/TextFieldDefaults#OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.InteractionSource,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function0))

It is perfectly fine it is enabled but if i disable it textcolor is not changing like OutlinedTextField. It's textcolor still behave like it's enabled. What should i do ?

```
val colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()
    val text = "+56"
    BasicTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {},
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        enabled = false,
        singleLine = true,
        textStyle = TextStyle.Default,
        modifier = modifier
            .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .layoutId("country_code"),

    ){
        TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
            value = "+56",
            enabled = false,
            singleLine = true,
            innerTextField = it,
            visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            colors = colors

        )
    }
```

[image: WhatI] I want to make this.

[image: WhatsHappening] It's the my code's result. As you can see border is disabled but
the text is still enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the color of your `BasicTextField`'s `textStyle` to the color from `TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()`

```
val colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()
val enabled = false

OutlinedTextField(
    textStyle = TextStyle.Default.copy(color = colors.textColor(enabled).value),
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bug.
As workaround you can use something like:

```
   val colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()
   val enabled = false
   val textColor = colors.textColor(enabled).value
   val mergedTextStyle = TextStyle.Default.merge(TextStyle(color = textColor))

    BasicTextField(
        //your implementation
        textStyle = mergedTextStyle,
        ) {
        TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
             //your implementation
        )
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LocalTextStyle` property to replace text color.

```
 textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(color = Gray)
```